# How replaces values from a column in a Panel Data with values from a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database in panel data form:

```
Date id variable1 variable2
2015 1    10         200
2016 1    17         300
2017 1     8         400
2018 1    11         500
2015 2    12         150
2016 2    19         350
2017 2    15         250
2018 2     9         450
2015 3    20         100
2016 3     8         220
2017 3    12         310
2018 3    14         350
```

And I have a list with the labels of the ID

```
List = ['Argentina', 'Brazil','Chile']
```

I want to replace values of id with labels from my list.

Thanks in advance

```
Date id         variable1 variable2
2015 Argentina    10         200
2016 Argentina    17         300
2017 Argentina     8         400
2018 Argentina    11         500
2015 Brazil       12         150
2016 Brazil       19         350
2017 Brazil       15         250
2018 Brazil        9         450
2015 Chile        20         100
2016 Chile         8         220
2017 Chile        12         310
2018 Chile        14         350
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is the way to go, with `enumerate`:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(List, start=1)}
df['id'] = df['id'].map(d)
```

Output:

```
    Date         id  variable1  variable2
0   2015  Argentina         10        200
1   2016  Argentina         17        300
2   2017  Argentina          8        400
3   2018  Argentina         11        500
4   2015     Brazil         12        150
5   2016     Brazil         19        350
6   2017     Brazil         15        250
7   2018     Brazil          9        450
8   2015      Chile         20        100
9   2016      Chile          8        220
10  2017      Chile         12        310
11  2018      Chile         14        350
```

Comment: Works to me. Converting in numeric df['id']. Thank you, dear Quang.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`df['id'] = df['id'].map({1: 'Argentina', 2: 'Brazil', 3: 'Chile'})`

or

`df['id'] = df['id'].map({k+1: v for k, v in enumerate(List)})`

Comment: Hi, Kenan, Thank you with your comment but does not work still to me. Please, see my image (http://prntscr.com/r5hlkr) .

Comment: make sure your df['id'] is of dtype `int`